# Can't add transitions to a react component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, css-transitions

I am developing a React app with Tailwind CSS. I have created a ToolBar component with five elements. When the screen width is reduced, three out of the four visible elements disappear and the fifth element appears. By clicking the fifth element (represented by ≡, three lines), the previously hidden elements become visible. I have applied a transition property to these elements, but unfortunately, the transition does not occur when the user clicks the button. I suspect that this issue might be due to the React component being reloaded, but I am unsure about how to resolve it.

This is the code for the ToolBar:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { ToolBarItem } from "./toolBarElement";

export function ToolBar() {
    const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false)

    return (
        <nav className="h-[60px] sm:h-[70px] md:h-[80px] w-full shadow-2xl">
            <ul className="flex md:space-x-4  mr-[60px] justify-end">
                <li className="grid items-center h-[60px] sm:h-[70px] md:h-[80px] absolute top-0 left-[30px]">
                    <h1 className='font-rowdies text-2xl text-black'>Example text</h1>
                </li>

                <li className="grid items-center md:hidden h-[50px] sm:h-[60px] absolute top-0 right-[40px]">
                    <h1 onClick={() => setMenuOpen(!menuOpen)} className="font-rowdies text-4xl text-black ">≡</h1>
                </li>

                <ToolBarItem link="/" text="About me" menuOpen={menuOpen} />
                <ToolBarItem link="/about" text="Projects" menuOpen={menuOpen} />

                <li className="grid items-center h-[60px] sm:h-[70px] md:h-[80px]">
                    <button style={{ transition: 'all 1s' }} className={`text-white font-bold md:block py-[5px] md:py-[10px] px-[15px] bg-red-600 border-red-600 border rounded-[6px] shadow-red ${menuOpen ? '' : 'hidden'}`}>Resume</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    );
}
```

and this for ToolBarItem:

```
export function ToolBarItem({ link, text, menuOpen }) {
    return (
        <li className='grid items-center h-[60px] sm:h-[70px] md:h-[80px]'>
            <a style={{ transition: 'all 1s' }} className={`font-rowdies text-2xl text-black mx-[20px] md:block ${menuOpen ? '' : 'hidden'}`} href={link}>{text}</a>
        </li>
    )
}
```